# C# MySQL reader Error - "Sql Syntax Error"

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wpf, visual-studio

I am currently trying to make a Login System using Visual Studios WPF application in the language C#. I am getting an error message every time the `Login_Button_Click` function runs. The Error message shows a specific line of code `var DataReader = TeacherLoginsCommand.ExecuteReader();`

I have checked countless videos and many videos seem to be doing the same thing without any problems. Any help is appreciated.

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow(){

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //When Login Button Is Clicked Do:
        private void Login_Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){

            //Gets Username And Password From Loing Screen
            string TeacherID = Teacher_ID.Text;
            string TeacherPassword = Teacher_Password.Password;

            //Connects To Database And Gets All Teacher Logins
            string connectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=teacherlogins;UID=root;PASSWORD=Password";
            MySqlConnection TeacherLoginsConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            string CurrentQuery = "SELECT * from teacherloginstable where ID = " + Teacher_ID;
            MySqlCommand TeacherLoginsCommand = new MySqlCommand(CurrentQuery, TeacherLoginsConnection);

            TeacherLoginsConnection.Open();
            var DataReader = TeacherLoginsCommand.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable TeacherLoginsTable = new DataTable();
            TeacherLoginsTable.Load(DataReader);
            TeacherLoginsConnection.Close();

            if (TeacherLoginsTable.Rows.Contains(TeacherPassword))
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Login Sucsessful", "Welcome" + Teacher_ID);


            }
            else {

                MessageBox.Show("Details Not Recognised", "Error: Details Not Recognised");

            }

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Alperton Login" Height="450" Width="625">
<Border Padding="50">
    <StackPanel Margin="5">
        <Image Source="download.png" Height="90" Margin="0, 0, 0, 20"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Teacher ID" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Padding="0,10"/>
        <TextBox Padding="5" x:Name="Teacher_ID"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Teacher Password" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Padding="0,10"/>
        <PasswordBox Padding="5" x:Name="Teacher_Password" />

        <Button Content="Login" Margin="0,10" Padding="0, 3" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Click="Login_Button_Click"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Error Message:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.TextBox' at line 1'
```

Comment: That is the wrong way to pass parameters and you  dont need to save the reader to a new variable. ExecuteReader will fill the DataTable.  Otherwise check the names of the table and everything.  Videos are a poor substitute for actual documentation

Comment: @Plutonix That was what I tried initially, It also give me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are a victim of your own unfortunate decision to give two variables with different purposes very similar names.

You have a textbox named `Teacher_ID` and you put the text of this in `TeacherID`.  Is it possible you used the wrong one in the query?

Have you tried examining the SQL query string you are sending to MySQL, either using a debugger or by using `Debug.WriteLine` or `Console.WriteLine`?  I expect you would see something like the following:

```sql
SELECT * from teacherloginstable where ID = System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
```

(`System.Windows.Controls.TextBox` is what you get when you call `ToString()` on a `TextBox`.)

Do you see the problem?

You could *possibly* fix it by using the correct variable name:

```
       string CurrentQuery = "SELECT * from teacherloginstable where ID = " + TeacherID;
```

But really, please don't do this.  Please don't build up SQL strings by concatenating values in.  It is much better to use parameterised SQL instead:

```
        string CurrentQuery = "SELECT * from teacherloginstable where ID = @teacherID";
        MySqlCommand TeacherLoginsCommand = new MySqlCommand(CurrentQuery, TeacherLoginsConnection);
        TeacherLoginsCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherID", TeacherID);
```

Comment: Ahh okay I see the problem now. Thanks for your help. I know it may seem like a rookie mistake, but that's just because I am a rookie XD.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
string TeacherID = Teacher_ID.Text;
```

Write

```
int TeacherID = Convert.toInt32(Teacher_ID.Text);
```

Comment: What Is the datatype of ID in your database table?

Comment: Its an int, they range from 1 - 3

Answer (score 0):

`Teacher_ID` is a TextBox id (x:Name) in XAML Code which refers a TextBox. You have to send its text attribute in sql statement.

Sql statement must be like this 
`SELECT * FROM teacherloginstable where ID = " + Teacher_ID.Text`;